# Make JavaScript image movement while scrolling smoother

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, parallax, smooth-scrolling

I have a background image that gets moved while scrolling. When the page is scrolled to top, the top edge of the background image touches to top edge of the window and when scrolled down 100%, the bottom image edge touches the bottom window edge.

This is my working code:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    var backgroundImage = document.querySelector('#background img');
    var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
    var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    var innerHeight = window.innerHeight;

    backgroundImage.style.top = (((backgroundImage.scrollHeight - innerHeight) / 100) * ((scrollTop / (innerHeight - scrollHeight)) * 100)) + 'px';
});
```

The result is what I'm expecting, but the scrolling gets extremely laggy. Is there a possibility to make this animation smoother?

**EDIT**

I added `requestAnimationFrame` like so:

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function() { requestAnimationFrame(process); });

function process() {
    // calculation code goes here
}
```

This makes the scrolling much smoother and the image movement is kinda perfect. But still the DOM isn't scrolling really smooth. Better, though not good. Any ideas for further improvements?

Comment: Okay, so `debounce` would be wrong... `throttle`, however, might work. Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3JwL/4/light/) using lodash. Seems pretty smooth - try it on your real project and let me know. You also might use css transforms rather than `top`.

Comment: Which browser did you use? I tested it with Safari (more laggy than debounce, actually) and Chrome (doesn't work at all)...

Comment: @brbcoding: Please make an answer with CSS Transforms! This was a great tip and the scrolling is now as smooth as hell!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CSS transforms might help... I use a 3d transform here, hopefully giving you even more performance thanks to [hardware acceleration](http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d).

The code would look something like this:

```
var updateImgPosition = function  () {
    var backgroundImage = document.querySelector('#background img');
    var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
    var scrollTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    var innerHeight = window.innerHeight;

    backgroundImage.style.webkitTransform = "translate3d(0,"+ (((backgroundImage.scrollHeight - innerHeight) / 100) * ((scrollTop / (innerHeight - scrollHeight)) * 100)) + "px,0)"

};

document.addEventListener('scroll', updateImgPosition)
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w3JwL/6/)**